# How to update threadContext with Spring Webflux Webclient wiretap logging

Tags: java, log4j, webclient

With the wiretap feature, I can see the log generated when WebClient is doing the request. However, the log does not contain the value I set with `threadContext.put` statement in the main program. I understand this is because wiretap is under a different thread. Is there any way to perform `threadContext.put` for wiretap as well?

Answer (score 5):

You are suffering from the common context propagation problem. From a Reactor perspective you can read more about it in Dariusz Jędrzejczyk's blog series ([part 1](https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/28/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-1-the-basics), [part 2](https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/29/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-2-the-bumpy-road-of-spring-cloud) and [part 3](https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/30/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-3-unified-bridging-between-reactive)).

Reactor 3.5 and Reactor Netty 1.1 introduced an interesting solution to this problem: they support Micrometer's [`context-propagation`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/context-propagation) library. To profit from this support you need to:

1. Register a [`ThreadLocalAccessor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/context-propagation/latest/io/micrometer/context/ThreadLocalAccessor.html) that will help transfering the correlation id from Log4j's `ThreadContext` from and to various context objects:

   ```java
   private static final String CORRELATION_ID = "correlationId";
   ...
   ContextRegistry.getInstance()
       .registerThreadLocalAccessor(
           CORRELATION_ID,
           () -> ThreadContext.get(CORRELATION_ID),
           v -> ThreadContext.put(CORRELATION_ID, v),
           () -> ThreadContext.remove(CORRELATION_ID)
       );
   ```
2. Add one of the `contextWrite/contextCapture` operators at the end of your `WebClient` chain to capture your correlation id into a Reactor [`Context`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html) object:

   ```java
   webClient.get()
            ...
            .contextCapture();
   ```
3. All Reactor Netty pipelines consist of two parts: a sequence of Reactor operators and a sequence of Netty [`ChannelHandler`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html)s.  Reactor operators should automatically restore the thread locals, when they jump between threads. At the moment this does not seems to be the case for tasks started by the Netty part. Since `wiretap` works as a Netty handler, inbound events will **not** have a correlation id (only code executed in the Reactor part will have it). In order to correct that you need to restore the context manually via a `ChannelInboundHandler`:

   ```java
   private static final class ContextInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

       private static final ContextSnapshotFactory SNAPSHOT_FACTORY = ContextSnapshotFactory.builder()
           .contextRegistry(ContextRegistry.getInstance())
           .build();

       private static Scope setThreadLocals(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
           return SNAPSHOT_FACTORY.setThreadLocalsFrom(ctx.channel());
       }

       @Override
       public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
           try (final Scope s = setThreadLocals(ctx)) {
               super.channelRegistered(ctx);
           }
       }
   // Same for all other events
   ...
   }
   ```

   and add it as first Netty inbound Handler:

   ```java
   final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
       .wiretap(true)
       .doOnChannelInit((connectionObserver, channel, remoteAddress) -> {
           channel.pipeline()
               .addFirst("context", new ContextInboundHandler());
   });
   final WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
       ...
       .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
       .build();
   ```

Support for `context-propagation` is quite recent in Reactor Netty. It will probably improve in the future.

Comment: Implementing custom `ChannelInboundChannel` fixed problem for me. You can track official support on this:
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3478

Comment: Have you a complete example? I did every thing that you describe and still it doesn't work

Comment: @5frags: I'll try to write down an example next weekend.

Answer (score 0):

May be filter functions can help you here.

Edit: If you want to use the value in response, you can directly use it in response like this:

```
 @Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> {
            String value = ThreadLocalContext.get("test-variable");
            LOGGER.info("Value = " + value);
            return next.exchange(request)
                    .doOnNext(clientResponse -> {
                        //You can modify this code to put all the values as a map from thread local
                        ThreadLocalContext.put("test-variable", value);
                        LOGGER.info("Value = " + value);
                    });
        }).build();
    }
```

Note: You can reenter the value in that thread's context if it is needed at all. That is just how you want to implement.

(Also you can change the .doOnNext to some other function based on the use case)

Comment: Thanks, actually I tried to replace wiretap with filter(exchangeFilterFunctions ) to log request and response. added two ExchangeFilterFunctions function, one for request (Exchangefilter.ofRequestProcessor), another one for response(Exchangefilter.ofResponseProcessor). It works with request one. For response, since it is on another thread to capture the response, the ThreadContext is still null

Comment: @mememoremore The above answer should help you use the thread context in the response scope, you can modify the method based on your need.